# Dual router sate in Ionic Angular application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic project. The view for the web is divided on two main visual functional parts.
Both parts have their own deep navigation (like two iframes, containing big websites).

Is it possible to make a routing for two parts, so the URL should represent the state in the first part and in the second part simultaneously?

If yes, this can be achieved? I'll appreciate an examples.

Comment: Try to differentiate with query params.